# Find drive/partition with maximum free disk space using Windows command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, 3dsmax, maxscript

I have no clue about Windows programming hence here's what I am trying to do. I am currently writing a script in 3DS Max which can run Windows commands internally using max script. Here's the list of things I am looking to do using Windows commands:

- find the maximum free space available on a Windows based PC (e.g C:, D:, E:)
- this would compare free space available between all the volumes/HDD/partitions on that particular PC
- then create a temp dir on the partition with maximum available free space
- this command would be run locally by the software as our render management system opens 3DS Max separately on all systems which in turn can run the Windows commands.

Comment: start with `wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=3 get caption,freespace`

Comment: You need to show some efforts on your own if you expect help here! Please remember that SO is not a free code writing service!

Comment: Thank you Stepahn had almost forgotten about thi spost... goning to check check your suggestion out :)